# Yii2 несколько модулей, валидация и сохранение

Tags: yii2, архитектура, проектирование

Есть к примеру два модуля - каталог продукции и сео. Все это выводится в админке на одной странице, т.е. каждый товар имеет свои хар-ки и сео описание. Все это как то надо проверить и сохранить. Но таблицы то разные, следовательно и модели. Т.е. первая модель Product и вторая Seo. У каждой свои поля разумеется. Вот и возникает вопрос пихать все в одну общую форму и потом разруливать или же сразу отправлять каждую форму на свой урл(сохраняется ajax поэтому можно асинхронно это сделать). Что посоветуете ?

Comment: Если сео в бехевиор положить?

Comment: Ну это как вариант сео, а так там что угодно может быть. Это просто как один из самых простых примеров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно в контроллере во view передавать две модели, а сохранение их сделать внутри трансзакции. Либо сделать отдельную модель в которую поместить все поля обоих моделей, провалидировать их. И уже внутри этой модели сделать метод save, который разложит данные по целевым AR и сохранит их в трансзакции.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема в том что модули друг о друге ничего не знают и не должны по сути. Поэтому видимо придется писать обертку для валидатора.

Comment: В этом и смысл, что каждая AR чиста (хотя как не знают, знают, реляции жеж),  а связывает их третья модель которая и реализует бизнес логику между ними. Это как раз хорошая практика. http://slides.rmcreative.ru/ вот на пример запись вебинара "Yii2 структура большого проекта"

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю чего там.